# File uploaded with XMLHttpRequest not in $_FILES array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload, slim

I am trying to upload a file to my PHP Slim web application using native javascript and `XMLHttpRequest`. This is the code I have:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
  var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/foo/bar', true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name', file.name);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size', file.size);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type', file.type);

  formdata.append("thefile", file);

  xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      console.log((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
    }
  }, false);

  return xhr.send(formdata);
```

According to the dev tools, the request is populated and sent correctly:

[image: Request]
But at the other end the $_FILES array is empty.

If I replace the javascript handling with a basic HTTP form POST, then the file IS visible in the $_FILES array. So clearly the issue lies with my javascript code, or something about the javascript upload that the server does not like.

Does anyone see any issue with my javascript code or has experienced any issues like this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you defined the variable file ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, my sloppy copy-pasting (originally that was a method call there, didn't want to complicate the code snippet).

Comment: @RavinderReddy It's passed in as an argument. Sorry, should have been clearer, this code is inside a function.

Comment: No one got any ideas at all?